# Is there a text reader class that can be link on xerces during parsing?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xerces-c

Original Title: How to derived a class from base class DOMDocument of XercesC?
From what I understand is that during parsing, below function will be called.

```
DOMProcessingInstruction* DOMDocument::createProcessingInstruction  (XMLCh* target, XMLCh* data)
```

If my target is my desired value, I can process the content of data.

But below code has error about abstract class.

```
class derived : public DOMDocument
```

From what I understand, all pure virtual function should be overridden.
But that is a lot(about 20 functions), what I wanted is only the above function (createProcessingInstruction()).

I might be wrong about using the DOMDocument.
Do you have codes that implements it as base class and overrides only some functions?
What I want is during parsing I need to catch each line so I can perform some specific processing.
I used DOMLSParser class, but the parsed data has no way to get the version indicated on file (different from XML version). For below sample, I should get 1.9 and not 1.0.

sample file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="shift-jis"?>
<!DOCTYPE bml PUBLIC "XXX" "employee.dtd">
<?emp emp-version="1.9"?>
```

(edited)
Background: I assumed that createProcessingInstruction() function will be called during parsing based on C# functionality. But I think the trigger was the text reader of C#. So it means that function will not be called in xerces.
My question will now be, is there a text reader in xerces that can be link during parsing. So they work side by side to read each line and to process parsing.